# C# - Inheritance, override

Tags: c#, inheritance, types

Can I do something like this? (Over-simplified because it's too complex)

```
abstract class A {
  public string Print() {}

  public static string DoPrint(A a, Type T) {
    ((T)a).Print(); // <-- This should call eg. A3.Print(), not A.Print()
  }
}

class A1: A {
  public new string Print() {}
}

class A2: A {

}

class A3: A {
  public new string Print() {}
}

class Somewhere
{
  A3 a3 = new A3();
  a3.DoPrint();
}
```

I have many classes (A1, A2, A3, and so on) that inherits from a base class (A)

I am trying to create the DoPrint() function above in class A.
Can it be done?

I tried this

```
  public static string DoPrint(A a) {
    a.Print();
  }
```

but it calls A.Print(), not A3.Print()

EDIT: Changed the title from "Pass a type as parameter?" because everyone was right, I could just use virtual (thank you!). The problem lied somewhere else, irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Why do you have the `new` keyword specified in `A1` etc's `Print` method declarations? If it was to shut up a compiler warning, take them back out and consider the advice that the warning gives you.

Comment: You dont need to pass the type. Just make Print method virtual in all classes and will work.

Comment: Why don't you make `Print` a `virtual` method? That's what `virtual` is for.

Comment: Also, the title of the question is totally misleading (obviously there is no trouble *passing a parameter*). I 'm not sure what the correct title would be though.

Comment: I still don't see from your edited question why you can't use inheritance. If something is too complex, that is often an indication of an issue in the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with normal virtual methods and inheritance?? Look at the use of virtual and override:

```
abstract class A { 
 public virtual string Print() {} 

  public static string DoPrint(A a) { 
     a.Print(); // <-- This WILL call eg. A3.Print(), not A.Print() 
  } 
} 

class A1 : A
{
    public override string Print() {}
}

class A2 : A
{
    public override string Print() {}
}
class A3 : A
{
    public override string Print() {}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Not all classes need to override Print(). What do you do in that case?

Comment: If not all classes need to override Print, you only override it in the classes that do need it and provide a base implementation in your base class. Still not a reason to not use inheritance with the information I have now...

Answer (score 3):

```
public static string DoPrint(A a) {
  a.Print();
}
```

would work, but you need to declare Print as virtual and override it.

```
    abstract class A {
      public virtual string Print() {}

      public static string DoPrint(A a) {
          a.Print();
      }
    }

    class A1: A {
      public override string Print() {}
    }

    class A2: A {
      public override string Print() {}
    }

    class A3: A {
      public override string Print() {}
    }

    class Somewhere
    {
      A3 a3 = new A3();
      A.DoPrint(a3);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I just realised not all classes override the Print() function. That's why it's not virtual.

Comment: It's not a requirement for all the classes to override it if its virtual.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using new, mark the base class' Print method as virtual, and then use override in the subclasses method declarations.

```
public virtual string Print() { }
```

And in subclasses:

```
public override string Print() { }
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was careless. Not all classes override Print(). That's why it is not virtual.

Comment: @aximili - Not all classes have to override Print. Once a method is marked as virtual, it is an *optional* override. Any classes that don't override Print, will use the baseline provided by the virtual or last override in the abstraction tree.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no. You can't. Unless you go to the level of reflection and find and invoke the `Print` method defined on `T` via that. Anything like interfaces or `dynamic` would select the *top-most* implementation.

However, I wonder if `Print()` here should be `virtual`:

```
abstract class A {
  public abstract string Print();
}

class A1: A {
  public override string Print() {}
}

class A2: A {
  public override string Print() {}
}

class A3: A {
  public override string Print() {}
}
```

and just call `a.Print();`. Polymorphism will then call the most-derived override of `Print()`.

Comment: Sorry actually not all classes override Print(). Question edited. This whole thing is indeed using Reflection everywhere. So how do you "invoke the Print method defined on T via that"? And does the top-most mean A in this case?

Answer (score 1):

`DoPrint()` is a static function.

You should call it this way:

`A3.DoPrint(a3, typeof(A3));`

or

`A3.DoPrint(a3, a3.GetType());`

Now, I don't understand why you want to do that. Why not simply have a virtual `Print()` in class `A` and override it in derived classes ?